# Model passed to web api is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, restsharp

I have the following line of code in my controller after the user has entered his/hers log in details

```
var userProfile = UserService.UserLogin(userLogin);
```

Which calls this a static class which is referenced when calling external Web Apis

```
  public static UserProfile UserLogin(UserLogin userLogin)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(Url);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/UserLoginApi/", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddBody(userLogin);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var userProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<UserProfile>(response.Content).Result;

        return userProfile;
    }
```

The above calls this Web Api without a problem, I can hit the break point set

```
 public UserProfile Get([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
 {
        UserProfile userProfile;

     return userProfile;
 }
```

But when I check the values inside userLogin within the Web Api they are null?

Now stepping through the controller, userLogin has the email address and password I have entered, going in the UserService.Login again the values still exists, when It gets to

```
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I expand request and see parameters has a count of 1 but when it hits the break point in my Web Api GET the userLogin is null?

I have also tried this within the UserService.Login

```
        request.AddBody(new UserLogin
        {
            EmailAddress = userLogin.EmailAddress,
            Password = userLogin.Password
        });
```

But again with no luck what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It works for me ```request.AddObject(userLogin);```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that as you are using FromBody you have to use Post method to send data.

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/UserLoginApi/", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
```

As per your method in question.

```
public UserProfile Get([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
{
 UserProfile userProfile;    
 return userProfile;
}
```

Your controller action is Get method and when you request with Url api/UserLoginApi/ and Get Method it will call above method and if you change post as per my suggestion you have to change controller method name as well If you don't want to do that then update controller action like this.

```
public UserProfile Get([FromUri] UserLogin userLogin)
     {
        UserProfile userProfile;    
         return userProfile;
     }
```

Call With following thing.

```
 public static UserProfile UserLogin(UserLogin userLogin)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(Url);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/UserLoginApi/", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddQueryParameter("EmailAddress", userLogin.EmailAddress);
        request.AddQueryParameter("Password", userLogin.Password);    
        var response = client.Execute(request);    
        var userProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<UserProfile>response.Content).Result;    
        return userProfile;
    }
```

if you decided to use Post Method then make controller action like

```
public UserProfile Post([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
{
 UserProfile userProfile;    
 return userProfile;
}
```

And you should call like this.

```
public static UserProfile UserLogin(UserLogin userLogin)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(Url);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/UserLoginApi/", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddBody(userLogin);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var userProfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<UserProfile>(response.Content).Result;

        return userProfile;
    }
```